# Magento Integrity constraint violation

Tags: magento-1.9

I 'm getting the following error:

```
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
> 
> Trace:
> #0 /home/hofb/web/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
> #1 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
> #2 /home/hofb/web/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
> #3 /home/hofb/web/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
> #4 /home/hofb/web/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
> #5 /home/hofb/web/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
> #6 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(174):
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor_inf...', Array)
> #7 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(108):
> Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveVisitorInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
> #8 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(463):
> Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
> #9 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
> #10 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
> #11 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
> #12 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor),
> 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
> #13 /home/hofb/web/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
> #14 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527):
> Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
> #15 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
> #16 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
> #17 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
> #18 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #19 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #20 /home/hofb/web/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #21 /home/hofb/web/index.php(152): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #22 {main}
```

Any ideas how i can fix that? I have 3 websites on the same magento installation.

-- UPDATE --

I fixed that and now i am getting the following error

Unknown number format type 'array'. Format 's:12:"#,##0.00 ¤"; 7200 1464778224 8' must be a valid number format string.

```
> Trace:
> #0 /home/hofb/web/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php(307): Zend_Locale_Format::_checkOptions(Array)
> #1 /home/hofb/web/lib/Zend/Currency.php(194): Zend_Locale_Format::toNumber(0, Array)
> #2 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(270):
> Zend_Currency->toCurrency(0, Array)
> #3 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(242):
> Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatTxt(0, Array)
> #4 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php(222):
> Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->formatPrecision(0, 2, Array, true,
> false)
> #5 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php(1004): Mage_Directory_Model_Currency->format(0, Array, true)
> #6 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Helper/Data.php(61): Mage_Core_Model_Store->formatPrice(0)
> #7 /home/hofb/web/app/design/frontend/default/crazy_1/template/checkout/cart/mini_cart_top.phtml(8):
> Mage_Checkout_Helper_Data->formatPrice(0)
> #8 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/hofb/web/...')
> #9 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
> #10 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
> #11 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
> #12 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #13 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('top_cart', true)
> #14 /home/hofb/web/app/design/frontend/default/crazy_1/template/page/html/header.phtml(50):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('top_cart')
> #15 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/hofb/web/...')
> #16 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
> #17 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
> #18 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
> #19 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #20 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
> #21 /home/hofb/web/app/design/frontend/default/crazy_1/template/page/1column.phtml(31):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
> #22 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/hofb/web/...')
> #23 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
> #24 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
> #25 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
> #26 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
> #27 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
> Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
> #28 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
> #29 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
> 'homepage')
> #30 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45):
> Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
> 'homepage')
> #31 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
> Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
> #32 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
> #33 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
> #34 /home/hofb/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
> #35 /home/hofb/web/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
> #36 /home/hofb/web/index.php(152): Mage::run('', 'store')
> #37 {main}
```

I am using the same template on another website without getting similar error. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was apc cache.

APC was enabled for the main main domain but not for the second one.

Enabling APC across all domains solved the prolbem

Answer (score 0):

go to your magento shell directory and php -f log.php -- clean -- days

Hopefully error will be removed

Comment: php -f log.php -- clean --days (speficied days) or just truncate your logs tables